# magento bulk products upload images but do not display in version greater than 1.6?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

**These are the steps i followed :**

1. I created a category and added product to it in the backend of
   magento
2. System->Import/Export-> "export" the csv file .
3. Removed the current values of the product already added then added
   values new values to it.
4. Copied that csv file to media/import directory where images to be
   uploaded were also present. (value = /image001.Jpg)
5. Went on to import and it says import successfully.

**Output :**

Products with the data uploaded successfully

**BUT**

No relevant images found, while i can see images uploaded in media/catalog/product..... folder

I have visited many many blogs forums, spent alot of hours for it but in vain. So in last i am posting it over here.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can post in the whole process in steps with sample Csv file and also tell us required fields and values for fields ib brief.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience you have to make sure you put the image information in all the right places in the import CSV file.  The three sets of image columns (image, image_label; small_image, small_image_label; thumbnail, thumbnail_label) are what set which image will be used for what purpose.  And, they are one image per product.

However, it is the media images columns (_media_attribute, _media_image, _media_lable (yep, misspelled in Magento), _media_position, and _media_is_disabled) that actually define the image(s) for the product.  These media image columns have to be completed on a one row per image basis.  The _media_attribute is the id of that attribute (77 in my experience).  The _media_image is that actual name of the image file in your media/import directory (case sensitive). The _media_lable is the title you want on the image.  _media_position is the relative order of the images for this product. _media_is_disabled is the flag for each image that identifies whether the image is shown in the product media group or not.

Comment: thanks @pcproffitt :) it did the magic i was looking for, but can you tell me what to do for multiple images for a product ?

Comment: There can only be one image designated as base image (image, image_label), small image (small_image, small_image_label), and thumbnail (thumbnail, thumbnail_label). When adding multiple images, just add one image for each row.  However, you can add multiple rows within the various media images columns. All the rest of the columns in the import will be blank - just the media image columns used.  These have to be immediately following the primary product definition row.

Answer (score 0):

I try this also  pcproffitt: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202982/pcproffitt

I have noticed that in my .csv file the columns were only (image, image_label; small_image, small_image_label; thumbnail, thumbnail_label) - that was from my Magento1.3 export but when I try to import it there is no error in importing but the Images were not seen on the site.

Then I found your Answer that in new version of Magento1.6 the column name is defferent it is (_media_attribute, _media_image, _media_lable (yep, misspelled in Magento), _media_position, and _media_is_disabled)

Whoops! I'm badly solving this. What would your suggestion though since I have 7000 plus products and images on my old site to transfer :( Is there a way to make this things gonna work out?

Thank you Sir!